# Is there a way to use the "which"-function on several matrix rows without using & several times?

Tags: r, subset

I am working with relatively large matrices (2197x100) and need to quickly select specific rows. The first 7 columns are values with which I can identify the needed rows, as in this example:

```
design_matrix = matrix(c(rep(1:3, each = 729),
                   rep(rep(1:3, each = 243), 3),
                   rep(rep(1:3, each = 81), 9),
                   rep(rep(1:3, each = 27), 27),
                   rep(rep(1:3, each = 9), 81),
                   rep(rep(1:3, each = 3), 243),
                   rep(1:3, 729)),
                   nrow = 2187)
```

I know I can use the function `which()` to find rows of a matrix with specific values. I am also aware I can use & to use multiple criteria. Since I need to check several entries multiple times, I am trying to find a way to do something like this:

```
which(design_matrix[,1:6] == c(1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

to get the rows with the respective values, in this case c(1,2,3). Instead I get the TRUE values of each element-wise comparison. Is there a way to do this without having to use mutliple & like in

```
which((design_matrix[,1] == 1) & (design_matrix[,2] == 1) & (design_matrix[,3] == 1) & 
  (design_matrix[,4] == 1) & (design_matrix[,5] == 1) & (design_matrix[,6] == 1))
```

which does what I want but would need to be rewritten whenever I need different values?
I'm using the `which()` function to subset my data as in `design_matrix[which(design_matrix[,1]==1),]`, so if there is an easy way of doing this using `subset` that would also answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sweep` with margin `2` and the function `!=`  and `rowSums` with `which` to get the rows which have `c(1,1,1,1,1,1)`.

```
which(rowSums(sweep(design_matrix[,1:6], 2, c(1,1,1,1,1,1), "!="))==0)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a key to make lookup trivial and less computationally expensive if you have to do this a lot:

```r
key <- apply(design_matrix, 1, paste0, collapse = "")
design_matrix[key == "2133132", ]
#> [1] 2 1 3 3 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `apply()`:

```
which(apply(design_matrix[,1:6], 
            1, 
            function(row) 
              all(row == c(1,1,1,1,1,1))
            )
      )
# [1] 1 2 3
```